Transcribe bass notes
I would like to transcribe songs mainly to extract the bass notes and practice them.
During the process, I have tried a couple of tools. But if the song has more instruments, then both tools fail.
I am able to get the key signature and pick the right notes through ear training - but this works if the bass lines are clear and tempo is slow.. but duration of the note and sometimes lack of clarity means it is not necessarily easy.
How should I approach transcribing?

There are kind of two separate issues here: 1) isolating the bass and 2) transcribing. By far the best thing, though it's not fast, is to simply get better at transcribing, or ask another human to do it for you. As for isolating, the simplest and quickest tool is the lowpass you mentioned; just start by cranking down the EQ. If that doesn't give you enough clarity you can pursue more complicated measures, but start there.

Also by the way: "Point me toward a tool to do X" questions aren't on-topic here; they're best converted into questions that focus more on "How do I do X." This question has good tips for isolating an instrument. I would add to that, make sure you're working with the best audio file you can, and try various playback devices (speakers, headphones, etc) to see what does it best

As per Andy's comments, I have edited to make this on topic.

We tend to have a harder time discerning the pitch of very low notes.  You may find it helpful to digitally pitch shift the song up an octave when transcribing.  However, I have found that even state-of-the-art algorithms such as Zplane Elastique 3 can add enough warbling artifacts to sometimes confuse note lengths and rhythms.
You can pitch shift up an octave at full fidelity by speeding up playback, but then everything happens twice as fast!  Still potentially helpful, but fast rhythms might get out of hand.  I find that I get the best results by splitting the difference- speeding up by 50% (you transcribe the notes up a fifth and transpose back down afterwards.)
Another software tool that is potentially useful is a spectrum analyzer such as SPAN.  Adjust the window settings so that you get enough frequency resolution to target individual notes.  However, any given note will have many harmonics, so you need to take care to pick the right one- which should be fairly easy with bass, as it would usually be the lowest pitch instrument playing at any time.  Perhaps there are some tools that will overlay note names on the spectrum display- otherwise, you would have to look up the frequencies on a chart to find the note name.

Good points not only are 50Hz and 60Hz closer together than 100Hz and 120Hz (an octave higher), it's also that our ears are accustomed to be most perceptive to speech https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_range#/media/File:H%C3%B6rfl%C3%A4che.svg so the bass end might have poor detection anyway, which is often why the melody section is played by the higher sounding instruments. The problem of note length detecion is finding a balance between not ignoring fast note changes as "random noise" while avoidign picking up on  actual noise and adding 256th notes and whatnot.

Ideally you'd map out notes and pauses and play only the note parts faster faster and longer (multiply with the same value). Though as there is rarely actual silence detecting pauses is not that easy for a computer and cutting off notes likely messes with the sound as well. Not to mention that doing it manually is pretty tedious.

interesting suggestions here.

Transcribing for me, 60 odd years ago, involved very careful listening. There were no 'tools' to try to rely on then!
Get used to knowing your scales, and particularly the arpeggios produced from them as most bass lines will be using those notes. It would be rare for a bassist to use many other notes - they would simply be out of tune.
One 'tool' that we didn't really have then was an equaliser apart from treble and bass controls - but now, parametrics and graphics could be useful to enhance the bass registers and defeat the higher ones, making the job of discerning bass lines easier.
So, don't use the so-called 'tools' - real composers never used them - they relied on their musical knowledge and expertise - both of which are within your reach with some effort, which will always put you in good stead for whatever comes next, musically.

thanks for the suggestion. I take it that there are both software and hardware equalisers to low pass filter non bass audio...
do I stick to less than 400hz then ?
also, the kick drum and human voices are sometimes less than 400 and may be the double bass... so I think there will be some overlap...

You'll never isolate one particular thing completely. However, with judicious use of eq. and panning, it's possible to isolate pretty well. Kick sounds nothing like bass anyway, and often follows the bass rhythm pattern.

“It would be rare for a bassist to use many other notes”  What about passing notes?  While root notes are obviously the most common, and other chord tones relatively so, IME most songs have a fair few passing notes too.

@gidds - passing notes, by definition, are 'stepping stone' notes in between two important ones. Once one has established which those important ones are, how difficult is it to find the passing notes. Maybe I should have added that into the answer, but I assumed it would be implicit.


I am able to get the keysignature and pick the right notes through ear training - but this works if the bass lines are clear and tempo is slow.. but duration of the note and sometimes lack of clarity means it is not necessarily easy.

Presumably your programs faces the same or a very similar challenge. Like the shape of a note usually has a somewhat distinctive amplitude envelope for different instruments (idk key, string, wind etc) and the range of your instrument determines a region of frequencies. So you could help it by doing that manually, idk find an equalizer and up the volume on the bass and tone down the high end. Or kick out the patterns that correspond to other instruments, but I guess that's the "magicical ai stuff" that your programs performs already.
Though if lots of stuff happens at the same time, all these things overlay and separating things becomes a lot more difficult.
Also for the rythm you could clap along and record yourself doing so. That should most likely tell you the tempo, time signature and where the beats are. And if you know what note is played on the beat or between beats you could already construct a rudimentary corps that might already sound something like the piece you're actually trying to play which you can then further flesh out by hearing and trying to reproduce.
And if you're a newbie, it might already be ok if it's challenging and sounds good. Maybe that's even better than the real deal if that is above your level.
Also you might as well look out if you could buy the actual sheet music somewhere ;)

Often the actual sheet music doesn't necessarily reflect what actually gets played.

@Tim You mean because the musician never learned sheet music and people just tried to transcribe it or because the sheet music is more of an "inspiration" and the interesting parts were improvised?

Reading doesn't come into it. Often, it's written simply, and isn't exactly (by any means) what actually got played.

some songs dont have sheet music... let us say songs from a different language.

@NRB But if things have never been formalized or written down how do you know what "the real deal" is, besides whether it sounds right to you, which is something that you could readily confirm by yourself, right?

when I mean, we dont have sheet music, I meant I dont have access to the sheet music for some of the songs played as part of a movie.. and obviously they are not sold publicly either... hence I have to listen to the song and then grasp as much possible
